# How to replace a tag with another in sql server XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml.modify

I am working on a table in sql server which stores xml file in a column. In that xml file I am doing some changes. The XML file looks like:

```
<Report version=1>
 <Title>
   <Student>
         <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" name="age" description="Age 
          of student">
            <Value>20</Value>
         </InputNumber>
         <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" name="height" 
         description="height of student">
             <Value>170</Value>
         </InputNumber>
   </Student>
 </Title>
</Report>
```

I understand the usage of modify function for updating attributes or text present between tags as:

```
UPDATE student
SET dataxml.modify('replace value of (/Report/@version)[1] with "2"')
WHERE id=10
or
UPDATE student
SET dataxml.modify('replace value of (/Report/Title/Student/InputNumber[1]/Value[1]/text())[1] with "21"')
WHERE id=10
```

But now I want to replace entire tag with another tag i.e.

```
         <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" name="height" 
         description="height of student">
             <Value>170</Value>
         </InputNumber>
```

with

```
         <InputText name="height" 
         description="height of student">
             <Value>170 cm</Value>
         </InputText>
```

I found something on internet like this and tried.

```
Update Student
   set dataxml = replace(cast(dataxml as nvarchar(max)),'/Report/Title/Student/InputNumber[2]>','InputText>')
WHERE id=10
```

It says updated successfully. But I don't see the change in XML.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Your XML is not valid. The attribute `version=1` must be `version="1"`.
Second: The verb *tag* is just one markup like `<Student>` or `</Student>`, but the whole node with attributes and nested sub-nodes is called *node* or - as a special type of node - *element*.

Now to your issue:

We need a declared table to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @student TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, dataxml XML);
INSERT INTO @student VALUES
(N'<Report version="1">
 <Title>
   <Student>
         <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" name="age" description="Age of student">
            <Value>20</Value>
         </InputNumber>
         <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" name="height" description="height of student">
             <Value>170</Value>
         </InputNumber>
   </Student>
 </Title>
</Report>');
```

--This is the new element we want to insert (better: want to use to replace another)

```
DECLARE @newElement XML=
N'<InputText name="height" description="height of student">
    <Value>170 cm</Value>
  </InputText>';

--approach one calls `.modify()` twice:

UPDATE @student SET dataxml.modify('insert sql:variable("@newElement") after (/Report/Title/Student/InputNumber[@name="height"])[1]');
UPDATE @student SET dataxml.modify('delete (/Report/Title/Student/InputNumber[@name="height"])[1]');

SELECT * FROM @student;
```

--approach two uses FLWOR-XQuery

```
UPDATE @student SET dataxml=dataxml.query('<Report version="{/Report/@version}">
                                           {<Title> 
                                            <Student>
                                            {
                                            for $elmt in /Report/Title/Student/*
                                            return
                                            if(local-name($elmt)="InputNumber" and $elmt[@name="height"]) then
                                               <InputText name="height" description="height of student">
                                                   <Value>{$elmt/Value/text()} cm</Value>
                                               </InputText>
                                            else
                                                $elmt
                                            }
                                            </Student>
                                           </Title>}
                                           </Report>');
```

Both ideas in short:

1) We insert the new element right after the one which should be replaced and remove it in a separate step.

2) We re-create the XML via XQuery by running through  the inner list of nodes within `<Student>` and insert the new content instead of the existing node.